# Terminate all old EC2 instance if created new by the user based on the Tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

**Problem Statement:** I want to give users permission to run an EC2 instance with Tags only, but I can't restrict the user to not running more than one EC2 instance at a time.

Hello Community,

Would it be possible to delete all old EC2 instances, if the user launches a new EC2 box? or restrict the user to not running more than one instance (the second point is not a feasible solution).

I want to give users AWS GUI and CLI access to perform the task.

Can someone suggest some solution to this problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: An alternate approach would be to Deny users the ability to launch instances. Instead, they should use an app (eg a web app) that you develop where they can request an EC2 instance to be launched. You could add logic to check whether they already have an instance and, if so, decline to launch a new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to give users permission to run an EC2 instance with Tags only

For this you can craft IAM policy as exemplified in AWS docs:

- [How can I use IAM policy tags to restrict how an EC2 instance or EBS volume can be created?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-policy-tags-restrict/)

> Would it be possible to delete all old EC2 instances, if the user launches a new EC2 box?

This requires a **custom solution**. For example, you can setup AWS CloudTrial trial that triggers a lambda function (through a AWS EventBridge) on `ec2.RunInstances` API call. The lambda function would check the ownership of the instance to be launched, how many a given user have them at present, and terminate pre-existing ones.